# Sympy yields `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'interval' and 'complex'` for complex rational expression

Tags: python, math, sympy, numerical-methods

I have this sympy script:

```py
from sympy import *
from sympy.plotting import plot_implicit

x, y = symbols('x y', real=True)

alpha = sqrt(2) / 2
expr = 1 + ((1-alpha) * x + y*I) / (1 - alpha * (x + y*I))**2

expr = Eq(abs(expr), 1)
p1 = plot_implicit(expr)
```

Which is trying to solve R(z) = 1 where:

As far as I can tell the expression I am giving it is correct. Why am I getting incompatible types? Note that if I get rid of the denominator I do get a plot.

[image]

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/makogan/Documents/University/Math521/A3/A5.py", line 49, in <module>
    p1 = plot_implicit(expr)
  File "/home/makogan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sympy/plotting/plot_implicit.py", line 430, in plot_implicit
    p.show()
  File "/home/makogan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sympy/plotting/plot.py", line 240, in show
    self._backend.show()
  File "/home/makogan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sympy/plotting/plot.py", line 1533, in show
    self.process_series()
  File "/home/makogan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sympy/plotting/plot.py", line 1530, in process_series
    self._process_series(series, ax, parent)
  File "/home/makogan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sympy/plotting/plot.py", line 1398, in _process_series
    points = s.get_raster()
  File "/home/makogan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sympy/plotting/plot_implicit.py", line 87, in get_raster
    func(xinterval, yinterval)
  File "/home/makogan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sympy/plotting/experimental_lambdify.py", line 272, in __call__
    return self.lambda_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'interval' and 'complex'
```

Comment: This is a bug. Please report to https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues

Comment: @OscarBenjamin reported https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/24870

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's caused by the fact that sympy's plotting module is using an old and obsolete evaluation module. If you [try this new plotting module](https://sympy-plot-backends.readthedocs.io/) you'll get the answer:

```py
from sympy import *
from spb import *
var("x:z")

x, y = symbols('x y', real=True)

alpha = sqrt(2) / 2
expr = 1 + ((1 - alpha) * z) / (1 - alpha * z)**2
expr = expr.subs(z, x + I*y)

expr = Eq(abs(expr), 1)
p1 = plot_implicit(expr, x)
```

[image]

Comment: ran pip install spb and tried to run this script I get the same error as before.

Comment: Read the [installation page](https://sympy-plot-backends.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html)...